# Save CTP post meta different values each day without overwriting previous values

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I have a Custom Post Type which fetches some data **every day** for each post and I need to store new values **while keeping the old ones**. 
If I use this, it will overwrite previous data:

```
update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'temperature', 25);
update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'humidity', 70);
update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ph', 7);
```

So I was thinking about using something like this to append time to name:

```
    update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'temperature-' . time(), 'some_value');
    update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'humidity-' . time(), 'some_value');
```

I got all this working, and now I got to the point where I want to **retrieve the latest two data for each post - values for yesterday and today**.
This is where I got stuck.

**Is there an easier/Wordpress way for saving the different data every day for every variable inside every CTP post?**

When retrieving these variables I was hoping to do it something like this, but maybe I have complicated more than I should have?

```
  $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'myctp',
        'posts_per_page' => -1 // Retrieve all CTP posts
        );
  $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if($query->have_posts())   :
         while($query->have_posts())  {

             $query->the_post();
             $post_meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID());

             // here get only 2 latest values for temperature, humidity, ph...

         }
    endif;
```

Comment: How many mycpt do you have? Have you considered a custom table instead of storing all the data points as post meta?

Comment: Yeah, I tried it later with a custom table but in the end I decided to go with Laravel

Answer (score 1):

I'm agree with the comment of @birgire, but if you really want to do it with custom fields, I think it's better to group all datas for a post in one custom field in an array.

After, you only need to use `get_post_meta` to get older values and add the new one in the array. Eventually, you could apply a php function to the array limite to 5 days. `update_post_meta` will save it as an array, to get it in your template, just create a display function.